# Problems unstaking ZRX from Validator VolleyFire using Coinbase Wallet

Tags: coinbase, validators, protocol, reward, stake

I am trying to unstake 1,592.83 ZRX from Validator VolleyFire using Coinbase Wallet, but https://governance.0xprotocol.org/account only takes the transaction fees from my wallet and nothing else happens. It also shows some Lifetime Rewards, but cero Accumulated Rewards.

Could someone help me unstake and transfer safely my ZRX?

Thanks